# Automating creation of Java Web Services from plain POJOs

Tags: java, web-services

The objective of what I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple (atleast I think so it is).

I have a plain java class containing say a method doAction(SomeObject obj). I want to expose it as a CXF webservice and its WSDL from this. A bottom-up approach will be followed in this case.

Now for a single class or two I might use Eclipse's Web Service Creation Wizard.
But let's say I have 30-35 such cases, I was hoping to automate the process.

Any ideas on how to go about it?

Adding a little more info regarding the objective:

Lets say I have an interface,

```
public interface IProcessService {

public SomeObject doAction (SomeObject input) throws Exception;

}
```

and I have its concrete implementation

```
@Service
@ManagedResource
public class ProcessServiceImpl implements IProcessService {

public SomeObject doAction(SomeObject input) throws Exception{
//doSomething
}
}
```

Now I could probably parse the interface or the concrete service to generate the following service interface to be exposed as:

```
@WebService (targetnamespace="...", name="...", portname="...", serviceName="...")
public interface IExposedService{

@WebResult(name="output", targetnamespace="...")
@RequestWrapper(...)
@ResponseWrapper(...)
@WebMethod(action="...")
public SomeObject doAction( @WebParam(name="input") Someobject input) throws Exception;

}
```

My target is to generate the last interface pragmatically.

Comment: Can you describe what output you want (you mentioned WsTest classses)?

Comment: Updated, the question

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jdk-tool [wsgen](http://%60https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html). It requires, that your Webservice Class has the annotation @WebService.

Example:

Service:

```
package org.wstest;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class WsTest {
    public String doAction(MyObject o){
        String result = o.getText() + " - " + o.getNumber();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Object

```
package org.wstest;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class MyObject implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 806129776947567877L;
    private String text;
    private int number;
    public MyObject() {
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Wsgen call:
(Assuming that the current folder contains the classes (folder `org` and subdirs with .class files) and an folder `out`)

```
wsgen.exe -wsdl -d out -cp . org.wstest.WsTest
```

This will create several files, including a wsdl.
I don't have the infrastructure to test the generated wsdl though.

You could then write a batch script to generate the wsdls for all your classes.

Comment: Yes but my objective is to generate the  WsTest class itself, not just the wsdls.
Regarding the wsdl generation part, yes that is certainly a way I believe. Will test it out.